# How can I access a Javascript file that is out of the document root?

Tags: javascript, html

My website is in `/var/www/html`.

I have a few files (`PHP` and `Javascript`) that are one level up, in `/var/www`.

I'm able to access the `PHP` file for my MySQL login credentials, but I can't access the `Javascript` file. In the `<head>` of my Login document, this is how I have it:

```
<script src="../sha256.js"></script>
```

This worked fine until I moved the `sha256.js` file. But now, when I try to login, the document can't find the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I access a Javacsript file that is out of the document root?

No.

If it isn't under the Document Root then it doesn't have a URL<sup>1</sup>.

If it doesn't have a URL then the browser can't request it.

Given the URL `http://example.com/` and the relative URL from it `../foo` the browser will delete a 'directory' off the end of the URL for each `../`. If there aren't any, then it will ignore them. Thus it resolves to `http://example.com/foo`.

> I'm able to access the PHP file for my MySQL login credentials

This is, presumably, server side code which deals with the server's *file system* and not with URLs.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a simplification. There are other ways (alias, mod_rewrite, etc) to give a file a URL, but for your purposes, moving the file under the Document Root is the simplest solution.

Comment: Unless their is a `RewriteRule` or a PHP front controller that can look at the `REQUEST_URI` to decide whether to load a resource from outside the document root or not.

Comment: Lol, well I think you just covered that. +1

Comment: @Quentin - Okay. So if I have to have this file in the document root, how can I hide so no one can access it's contents? This file contains the password hashing algorithm. I'd really like to keep this away from prying eyes.

Comment: @Landslyde you can't hide it. If your page needs the browser to fetch the code, then it has to be in an accessible URL.

Comment: @Landslyde — You can't … but you shouldn't need to. Hashes are one-way and sha256 is a standard anyway. That said, you shouldn't need to hash the password on the client anyway. Hash it on the server … but use SSL to *encrypt* it when you send it to the server.

Comment: @Quentin - I use SSL. And the user's typed-in password is tested serverside. I'm new at this. And my thinking was that if someone had access to my password-hashing `Javascript` file, then it wld make it easier for them to hack accounts. But I guess I'm as safe as anyone else in this regard. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Landslyde The point is that you shouldn't use (client-side) Javascript to hash the password. Since you're using PHP you should use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash it server-side before storing it and then [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when you need to check if an entered password is correct. `password_hash` will handle doing things the right way (using a slow/iterating algorithm like bcrypt, instead of a fast hash like sha256, which is not meant for passwords, and automatically adding a random salt).

Comment: @Paulpro - Thank you for your advice. I'll definitely check out your suggestions.